# Handling multiple environments, spinning up environment for testing in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have a large-scale service architecture with multiple features. Currently there are 3 environments created apart from production, due to which there are issues in sharing environments across multiple teams working on the same application but different features.

What would be nice is if every programmer is able to test his/her code in an integrated environment before merging to master.

Is there a way in Azure DevOps where in we can spin up a new temporary environment for testing and can be teared down after the code is merged to master.
I am not sure how to get started on this. It would be great if someone can help me.